# show options depending on the key given in the object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Can't get typescript to show options depending on the key given in the object.
in TInspectorConfig I want the `type` type to reflect on the `options` type.

```
export type FormControlOptions = {
  input: {
    type: 'text' | 'number';
    placeholder?: string;
  };
  select: {
    options: { value: string; label: string }[];
  };
  color: {
    type: 'text';
  };
};
export type InspectorFormControls = keyof FormControlOptions;

type UnknownRecord = Record<string, unknown>;
type TInspectorConfig<TWidgetConfig> = Partial<{
  [key in keyof TWidgetConfig]: {
    type: InspectorFormControls;
    options: FormControlOptions[InspectorFormControls];
    label: string;
    defaultValue: TWidgetConfig[key];
  };
}>;
```

for example when using the type, static checking doesn't seem to mind

```
const x:TInspectorConfig<TestCnfg> = {
    a:{
        label: "test",
        defaultValue: "test",
        type:"input",
        options:{
            options: [], // <---- IntelliSense doesn't give an error despite "options" not being one of "input" options
        }
    }
}
```

minimal reproducible [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBi0C2BhCA7GKCAGwHkwYBLfAZzgF44BvAKDjkrzAFcYAuZm3YJkwAQHIYoGOLgAfOOLzdMAI2BRxAbiHswxAIYBjYAAsSAEw0B+ATUKcA5jvYBfF3BrBiwI-0HCcBAU1Hg0AkxwAG4GxNxing54znCG6sR2SY5wrgDaALoe7kJGJNARuiIoElIgMkU6xaCQsFWoAJJhKH7QGFA4+IQkdIwA1sCIEABm6Fi4BERkIbQ6LEgocAAqnTTdMNDzU5SOADybAOqUFo7AMIfHAHwMcAAKBrCUsSes7LnjiBw8HB-tMtpdrrd7o58hVAusEjs9r05oNFjQPOxglRaAI+gMFiRyNiwrlEb59lA8fMhsQaIVKmlvJkoE4MXArFMDNxiDAAGqxeICC5XG53fBHRx-Cb0tyNB6reFbYD2bB4KbZRg-YQGZlOAA0lVUfGUag0LFcLFKYXgID42y65IO4uOZ2VdzVjiemsqOq1gXYjIycAARFJ7MGDf7hByuTz+XEEqG3RHKnDRHxg5weDAU1HMcswnw-Xn88TwnACnq4AB6atwE4AWibDcBUmIlC8YVQFggyrwkjgjkoUVQBiBGiIUFTwgtgQtFqAA)